# CakePHP - creating subquery

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, subquery

My used CakePHP Version is 3.x
i need cakePHP to create this sql statement:

```
    SELECT messages.id, message, receiver_id, sender_id, conversation_id, users.id, users.username FROM 
(
    SELECT messages.id, message, receiver_id, sender_id, conversation_id
    FROM messages as messages
    ORDER BY created DESC
) AS messages
left join users on (users.id = sender_id)
WHERE (sender_id = 13 or receiver_id =13)
GROUP BY conversation_id;
```

I used the queryBuilder but i do not really understand what im doing ;)

This is my cake code:

```
$subquery = $messages->find()
        ->order(['Messages.created' => 'DESC']);
    debug($neededMessages = $messages->find('all')
        ->select()
        ->group('Messages.conversation_id')
        ->contain(['Users'])
        ->where(['OR' => ['sender_id' => $userId, ['receiver_id' => $userId]]]));
    $neededMessages->execute();
```

I think its only a little mistake in there.
Cakes debug output is this:
SELECT (SELECT Messages.id AS `Messages__id`, Messages.subject AS `Messages__subject`, Messages.message AS `Messages__message`, Messages.created AS `Messages__created`, Messages.conversation_id AS `Messages__conversation_id`, Messages.is_new AS `Messages__is_new`, Messages.receiver_id AS `Messages__receiver_id`, Messages.sender_id AS `Messages__sender_id` FROM messages Messages ORDER BY Messages.created DESC) FROM messages Messages INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Messages.sender_id) WHERE (sender_id = :c0 OR receiver_id = :c1) GROUP BY Messages.conversation_id

im missing the columns in the first select statement.
Can anyone help on this issue?
grretings maik...

Comment: You should add information about CakePHP version and database schema for clearly.

Comment: sorry, cakePHP 3.x
I added this information to my post :)
thanks

Comment: This is just an example that doesn't maky any sense right? Cause the subquery doesn't do anything special that make its use necessary. Anyways, I guess the problem will finally be that you cannot easily turn of field aliasing, which would be necessary in the subquery, because otherwise you'd end up with fields like `Messages.id AS Messages__id` which will cause the outer select of `Messages.id` to fail. Maybe ask ORM wizard and part time leprechaun tamer _jose_zap_ on IRC if he knows a workaround.

Comment: Hey, jose_zap here. I was writing an answer but realized that your query does not make much sense. Is there something missing in what you want to do? It seems like you just wanted to write ``select * from messages, join users on (...) where ... GROUP BY conversation_id ORDER BY created DESC``

Answer (score 0):

So, i have my results how i need.
Only thing that bothers me is that i now have arrays and no objects. Here is my code:

`$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $stmt = $conn->query('SELECT max(m.id) as message_id, message, receiver_id, sender_id, m.conversation_id, users.id as user_id, users.username from (select id, message, receiver_id, sender_id, conversation_id from messages order by created desc) as m left join users as users on (m.sender_id = users.id) group by m.conversation_id');
        $messages = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
        $this->set('messages', $messages);`

It would be great to read from other cake users how they solve this 'problem'...